# Conditionally precompiling assets on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails application on a web server. Since the development is not done on the server, I've made a small ruby shell script that I run on the server whenever I decide it's time to deploy the changes and update the application on the server. Basically that script performs a checkout from SVN, `bundle install`, `rake db:migrate` and finally `rake assets:precompile`.

Now, the first three tasks perform their own checks to determine what they need to change and what can remain the same, but the assets precompilation task seems to recompile everything every single time, even if I didn't change anything.

Now, for most of the updates, I don't really need to recompile the assets, since most changes will be to the ruby scripts. However, I'm pretty sure that if I remove that step from that update script, it's going to strike me when I least expect it, and it's going to be troublesome to figure out what the problem is.

So, is there a way to do a smart asset compilation, that checks what assets needs to be compiled and compile only them? Or at least to avoid compiling again when there there is no need to recompile at all?

Comment: If you've got the assets:precompile already hardwired in,  why do you care if it's unneeded?  Is it the time it takes to do the precompile?  Better safe than sorry I say.  The only thing that would be simple I can think of is check whether anything in app/assets has changed,  if nothing has,  you can skip the pre-compile

Comment: Checking `app/assets` should work. Is there a single place all the compiled assets are compiled into that I can compare modification timestamps with, or do I have to relay on SVN for this?